# How does TypeScript Record Type result in a index type?

Tags: typescript

The `Record` type in TS is defined as

```
/**
 * Construct a type with a set of properties K of type T
 */
type Record<K extends keyof any, T> = {
    [P in K]: T;
};
```

Based on that I assumed that `K` has to be a union of literal string types. The TypeScript docs confirmed my belief with an example (the only one for `Record`):

```
type ThreeStringProps = Record<'prop1' | 'prop2' | 'prop3', string>
```

However, when a base type is passed as `K`, like `string`, the result is an index type.

```
type T = Record<string, number>;
// T = { [x: string]: number; }
```

This is what I don't get. For all examples and explanations of mapped types in the docs, the right part of `[P in K]`, `K`, is a union of literal string types.

How is the result of the example above then an index type?